# state of the art for kodaira dimension of $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, moduli-spaces

What is the state of the art about the kodaira dimension (and rationality, unirationality, etc.) of the moduli spaces of $n$-pointed curves of genus $g$? When it is known and when not? It would be great to collect the references for all $g$ and $n$ but I don't want to look like being fishing for points... :)